# degree zero term of minimal free resolution

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R=k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$ where $k$ is a field, and let $I$ be a homogenous ideal. Suppose that $\cdots\to R_{1}\to R_{0}\to R/I\to 0$ is a (the) **graded** minimal free resolution of $R/I$. Is it always true that $R_{0}=R$?

To clarify: by minimal I mean that the image of the map $R_{i}\to R_{i-1}$ is contained in $\mathfrak{m}R_{i-1}$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal generated by the $x_{i}$. A graded minimal free resolution should be unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, unless $R/I = 0$. The natural homomorphism $R \to R/I$ is surjective and $R$ is a free $R$-module. But I don't understand what you mean by "minimal" and "the" in this setting.

Comment: Perhaps $I$ is a graded ideal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank of the zeroth term in the minimal resolution (which is free), in your situation, is the minimal number of generators of the module you are resolving. In your case, one.

Indeed, if $M$ is a finitely generated graded module and $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_m\}\subset M$ is a finite generating set composed of homogeneous elements of degrees $d_1,\dots,d_m$, you can check that the map $P=\bigoplus_{i=1}^mR(d_i)\to M$, which maps the generators of the free module to the $s_i$'s, is surjective and has kernel contained in $\mathfrak m P$. As you know that minimal resolutions are unique up to isomorphism, this checks my claim.